# Docker compose doesn't expose port 80 for a Linked Service setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here's the docker compose file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - blog-vol:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqlpass
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wpuser
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqluserpass

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wpuser
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: mysqluserpass
volumes:
    blog-vol:
```

I bring it up doing the usual

```
docker-compose up -d
```

For some reason http://localhost (port 80) or http://my_private_ip (port 80) doesn't resolve when it's up.

However when I change the "ports" config in the above to

```
ports:
 -"8000:80"
```

http://localhost:8000 and http://my_private_ip:8000 do work. Not sure what's going on with port 80. I do see that it's available. I tested port 80 by running an nginx instance by doing

```
docker run -p 80:80 -d nginx
```

This nicely exposes the service at port 80. I'm not sure what's going on with the above docker-compose config. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do the containers actually run when you docker-compose-up them? Is port 80 free by the time containers run?

Comment: run without -d to check the logs, maybe something doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the default Wordpress configuration in the official Docker image. I exposed the port for the above MySQL instance and connected to the Database Server. I inspected the WP configuration to realize that it has a fixed config for where the server is running including the port. I updated this and everything started to work as expected!